# "az vm run-command" with "sudo waagent -deprovision+user -force" does not return prompt

Tags: azure

I'm trying to create a Linux VM image using Azure CLI.
According to the Microsoft document below, before creating the VM image, I need to run "# sudo waagent -deprovision+user -force" command on the VM.

How to create an image of a virtual machine or VHD: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/capture-image

Instead of logging into the VM, I'm trying to use run-command as follows, but prompt does not get returned after the message " - Running ..".

```
# az vm run-command invoke -g rgName -n vmName --command-id RunShellScript --scripts "sudo waagent -deprovision+user -force"
 - Running ..
```

Could you give me some advice on this issue?